# Iterate through json and list a particular field using golang for aws sdk

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Using the backup summary aws sdk api for golang: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb?tab=doc#BackupSummary

```
resp, err := dynasvc.ListBackups(&dynamodb.ListBackupsInput
```

fmt.Println gives me this json

```
[{
  BackupArn: "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:xxxx",
  BackupCreationDateTime: 2019-09-03 12:22:52 +0000 UTC,
  BackupName: "xxx",
  BackupSizeBytes: 1463075,
  BackupStatus: "AVAILABLE",
  BackupType: "USER",
  TableArn: "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:blah",
  TableId: "1e0e7f7c",
  TableName: "mytable"
```

Using the follwing code:

```
for _, backup := range resp.BackupSummaries {
        fmt.Println(*backup.TableName)
    }
```

Sorry I wasn't clear. Ignore the last comments.

```
for _, backup := range resp.BackupSummaries {
        fmt.Println(*backup.TableName)
    }
```

Gives me all the table names.  But what I'm trying to do is list tables using something like string.Contains so I can filter them out.  So my question is how do I create a filter for the range so I can get back tables with names that contains foo.
I want to be able to do something like:

```
return strings.HasPrefix("foo")
```

Comment: please post a sufficient attempt at getting just the table names out and give any errors or explain what went wrong with your attempt

Comment: *"fmt.Println gives me this json"* FYI that is **not** json, that is a slice of structs representation as produced by `fmt`. *"Sounds easy enough but I'm blocked somehow."* **how** are you blocked? As far as I know looping over a slice to get at the elements' fields is the appropriate way to do it, what is it that makes you think it not to be, what is that's blocking you?